# Can't cast Double to Integer in Java

Tags: java, integer, double

I have a problem. I'd change `double` on `Integer` but I have this error:

> Cannot invoke intValue() on the primitive type double

Thanks for help!

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.PointerInfo;
import java.awt.Robot;

public class Clicker {

    void SetX(int xCoordinate) {
        this.xCoordinate = xCoordinate;
    }

    void SetY(int yCoordinate) {
        this.yCoordinate = yCoordinate;
    }

    static int xCoordinate= 30;
    static int yCoordinate = 40;

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        PointerInfo inf = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point p = inf.getLocation();

        System.out.println(p.getX());

        int xzCoordinate = p.getX().intValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631652/strange-behaviour-with-object-intvalue (maybe better)

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`Math.floor(p.getX())`
`Math.ceil(p.getX())` or
`Math.round(p.getX())`
depending on which one suits you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cast in your code.

`getX()` seems to return a primitive `double` and the compiler tells you that you can't invoke `intValue()` on a `double`.

Therefore use a cast

```
int xzCoordinate = (int)p.getX();
```

or one of the rounding methods provided by `Math` (see answer of @Zircon)

Answer (score 0):

That is not how to convert a primitive `double` to an `int`.  Java's `Point` objects store their values as `int`s, but for some reason the getter methods return `double`s.  You can cast `getX()` to an `int`

```
int xzCoordinate = (int) p.getX();
```

Or you can just use the field, which is `public`.

```
int xzCoordinate = p.x;
```